# Keep first n values in a column

Tags: excel

I'm working with an Excel file with more than a hundred columns containing thousands of values. However, I only need the first 504 values in each column and the remaining values in that same column need to be removed. The problem is that the values in the columns start in different rows.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a filter for the entire worksheet and filter out null values giving you a selection of good data or delete the null values using the filter to select the null values. From there, delete the lines below your desired range.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a macro for that.
Your macro will scan your current sheet and will copy selected cells to 
a new target sheet.

The macro has to include 2 loops:
outer loop will run on columns 
inner loop will run on cells on curnet column

for each column 
The inner loop will advance from cell 1 upwards untill it finds first cell 
that its not null, when it finds it you have to write code that will copy 
the next 504 cells on that same column to the target sheet

then the control will go to the outer loop that will increment to the next 
column

you can assign Constant for MAX_COLUMNS that when the code reaches it
the macro will end.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have no experience with writing macros or programming at all, so I think I will have to do it manually then.